# content showing before the page loads and when refreshing, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a search bar with a button which must be displayed every time you focus on the search bar, in order for you to understand [I record this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9Qa9CoFj_E&feature=youtu.be) where you can see in the top right of the screen the behavior I mentioned on the question, just right after the logging you would see a button "Cancel", and then I refresh the page around 3 times for you to see that the same is happening, at the end you will see that click on Cancel and the button takes around 2 seconds to disappear, and it must disappear immediately.

Look at my code and tell me what is going on, please

```
<div class="bar-subheader">

    <label>
      <input type="text"
             ng-model="query"
             ng-focus="showInput = true"
             ng-blur="showInput = false">
    </label>
    <!-- this is the cancel button -->
    <button class="button-clear"
            ng-show="showInput"
            ng-click="query = null">
      Cancel
    </button>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is Angular with Ionic for a mobile app

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

.state('app.login', {
  url:'/login',
  views:{
    menuContent:{
      templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
      controller:'AuthController'
    }
  }
})
//THIS IS THE ONE YOU ASKED ME.
.state('app.sports', {
  url:'/sports',
  views:{
    menuContent:{
      templateUrl:'templates/sportsList.html',
      controller:'SportsController'
    }
  }
})
```

**HERE IS THE CONTROLLER**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleMobile')
  .controller('SportsController', function($scope, $state, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading,
                                           AuthFactory, SportsFactory) {
    $scope.sports = [];
    $scope.customer = {};
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading Sports...<br><div class="button-icon icon ion-loading-d"></div>'
    });

    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (sports.length) {
          $scope.sports = sports;
        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }

      }, function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, function(err) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      $state.go('app.login');
      console.log(err);
    });
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/sportSelectionModal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-right'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.sportSelectionModal = modal;
    });

    $scope.displaySportSelectionModal = function() {
      $scope.sportSelectionModal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeSportSelectionModal = function() {
      $scope.sportSelectionModal.hide();
    };

    $scope.isSportShown = function(sport) {
      return $scope.shownSport === sport;
    };

    $scope.goToLines = function(league) {
      var linesParameters = {
        customerId: $scope.customer.customer,
        top: 10,
        familyGameId: -1,
        games: -1,
        sports: league.sport.id,
        leagues: league.id,
        periods: league.lineType,
        part: league.part
      };
      $state.transitionTo('app.lines', linesParameters);
    };
  });
```

Comment: whats your poison? ui-router+angularmobile? ionic? material design?

Comment: do you have a resolve clause on the route that is refreshing?, what happens if you test it on FF? does it crashes?

Comment: yes, the same happens

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "resolve clause"

Comment: the page refreshes or the browser crashes on FF?

Comment: actually I just tried again: sometimes crashes and sometimes happens the same as in Chrome.

Comment: it seems to me a routing issue, please confirm on the chrome dev tools if you get a digest cycle error or infinite loop error

Comment: on the browser console you say ? actually I am not getting any errors.

Comment: ok then can you paste the routing portion and controller of the page?

Comment: i see you have 2 redirects in your controller, my guess is that one of those is being triggered and takes you to other page and that other page redirects you back to the current one, set breack point s on all your state.go, and state, transition and see which launches and  why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it takes so long  but checkout these 2 fiddles, they work without problems

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
   <input type="text"
         ng-model="vm.query"
         ng-focus="vm.showInput = true"
         ng-blur="vm.showInput = false" />

   <button class="button-clear"
        ng-show="vm.showInput || vm.query"
        ng-click="vm.query = null">
   Cancel
   </button>

 </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', myController);

function myController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.query;
    vm.showInput = false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmu8544a/

Also you may want to use Fastclick.js or ngTouch

this other version relies on query to hide/show
http://jsfiddle.net/cmu8544a/3/